# Exactly what does "ignored tags" do?

Tags: discussion, tags

Maybe I stupidly missed the explanation somewhere...   When I set some ignored tag (under "interesting tags") - just how does this affect my experience on SuperUser?

Answer (score 2):

Questions on ignored tags are a bit faded out

[image]

The first question contains one of my "interesting" tags, the last one contains one of my ignored tags. The ones in between are "normal", in the sense that I haven't mentioned whether I find the tags interesting or not.

Comment: There is also an option to hide ignored tags in your preferences.

Comment: oo I didn't know that.